# How can I create a toolbar button to start a run configuration?

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

In our project, we have several run configurations.

[image]

For certain test scenarios, I find myself constantly having to run the same configurations in succession over and over again. This is cumbersome and can't be solved with the **Before launch** options in the configuration, as the configurations are long-running processes.

I know that I can press <kbd>F5</kbd> and pick a run configuration from the list and I know that I can invoke a run configuration from the **Search everywhere** action, but I want a simple button on a toolbar.

I can't find a way to do that. What am I missing?

Comment: *"What am I missing?"* The fact that those are 1) project-specific entity (which means that if another project is opened then the button will (should) do nothing) 2) they are actual configurations and not actual actions. In any case -- have you tried Run/Debug Config of [Compound](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/run-debug-configuration-compound.html) type?

Comment: @LazyOne Compounds don't work for us. They are too rigid. The IDE adjusts in many ways depending on project-level settings. I don't see why a simple button in the user interface shouldn't be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not currently possible, please vote for [IDEA-75078](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-75078) and linked tickets